Use SMA previous DOT as an exit price
Thank you for your help.
What would be the correct coding for:
"Use SMA previous DOT as an exit price"
I want to use the "DOT price" of the previous candle as a trigger, not to wait until the end of the current candle.
Thank youuuuu sooo much

I'm getting out too late.
Trying to get out as soon as it gets to the previous SMA dot.

If you want something like a trailing stop loss, you just refer to the value of your plot in strategy.exit().
If you want a fixed SL price when your exit condition is met, you need to define your SL price with the var keyword so that it keeps its value. You then need to update its value whenever your condition is true.
// Method 1:
val = ta.sma(close, 9)

strategy.exit("Exit id", "Entry id", stop=val)

// Method 2:
var float sl_price = na

if (exit_condition)
    sl_price := val

strategy.exit("Exit id", "Entry id", stop=sl_price)

Do not forget to reset sl_price to na so that it is invalidated for the new trade. I would do that as soon as you enter a new trade.
